# Javascript dark mode toggle not working with onClick

Tags: javascript, dom-events, darkmode

main.js:

```
   function darkModeToggle() {
    var element = document.body;
    element.classList.add("darkmode");
    localStorage.setItem("mode", "dark");
    let mode = localStorage.getItem('mode')

    if (mode === 'dark') {
        document.getElementById("darkmode-button").onclick = lightModeToggle();
        document.getElementById("darkmode-button").innerHTML = 'Light mode';
        localStorage.setItem("mode", "light");
        return false
    }

}


function lightModeToggle() {
    var element = document.body;
    element.classList.remove("darkmode");
    localStorage.setItem("mode", "light");

    let mode = localStorage.getItem('mode')
    console.log('Hello')

    if (mode === 'light') {
        localStorage.setItem("mode", "dark");

        document.getElementById("darkmode-button").onclick = darkModeToggle();
        document.getElementById("darkmode-button").innerHTML = 'Dark mode'
    }

}
```

I have a button in home.html

`<button onClick='darkModeToggle' id='darkmode-button'>Dark mode</button>`

But this does not work.. I want to store the settings of the user if they want dark mode or light mode in the website..

Why does my current code not work and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this all in one function. There is no need for two functions. Add a default class for example light to your body and then change it when clicking the button. So by default light is display if the user doesn't set a preference.

Using localStorage has the advantage that the user preference will be stored next time the user visits your site.

When clicking the button read the localStorage. If no value has been set yet, set it to the opposite of the default one.

```js
   window.onload = function() {
     setMode();
   };
    
   function setMode() {
     let mode = localStorage.getItem('mode');
     if(!mode) mode = 'light';
     document.body.classList.add(mode);
   }

   function toggleMode() {
    let element = document.body;
    let btn = document.getElementById("darkmode-button");
    let mode = localStorage.getItem('mode')
            
    if(!mode) mode = 'dark';

    if(mode == 'dark') {
       localStorage.setItem("mode", "light");
       element.classList.remove("dark");
       element.classList.add("light");
       btn.innerHTML = 'Dark mode';
       
    }
    else {
      localStorage.setItem("mode", "dark");
      element.classList.remove("light");
      element.classList.add("dark");
      btn.innerHTML = 'Light mode';
    }    
}
```

```css
body.light {
  background: #fff;
}

body.dark {
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<body class="light">
  <button onclick='toggleMode()' id='darkmode-button'>Dark mode</button>
</body>
```

Comment: This works, but does not store the value on refresh or visiting another page like about page.. It changes back to light mode

Comment: localStorage entries are valid as long as it's the same domain and the same protocol and should work across your page. To solve this add an onLoad Listener to add a class to the body based on the localStorage entry. Changed my code accordingly.

Comment: In local storage, the mode is set to dark but it does not use dark mode on screen.. I am using this with django as backend.. So is there any problem bcz of that?

Comment: Shouldn't have anything to do with the backend. I corrected a typo in my code. Check with the developer tools if the css classes are getting set properly

Comment: When I refresh, the `darkmode ` class is removed from the body

edit: made some edits and it worked.. Thanks a lot

Comment: Now I am getting another error.. When I reload a page in dark mode, the text changes to dark where as it has to be light...

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use button text to identify the mode instead of using localStorage. You don't need two different function to change the mode.

There is another problem in html. onClick event should be attached as below.

```
<button onClick='toggleMode()' id='darkmode-button'>Dark mode</button>
```

```js
function toggleMode() {
    let buttonText = document.getElementById("darkmode-button");
    var element = document.body;
    if (buttonText.innerHTML === 'Light mode') {
      element.classList.add("darkmode");
      document.getElementById("darkmode-button").innerHTML = 'Dark mode';
    }
    else
    {
      element.classList.add("lightmode");
      document.getElementById("darkmode-button").innerHTML = 'Light mode';
    }
}
```

```html
<button onClick='toggleMode()' id='darkmode-button'>Dark mode</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still have one problem.. When I visit another link in the same page, it does not user dark bg if it is on..
It does not use the same even on refresh
My default is light bg.. So when I refresh, it always goes to light bg.. Same happens when I go to a difference HTML page like about page